# How to update React.js version installed in Laravel to the latest version?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, npm, laravel-artisan

After creating a Laravel project using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` I installed react.js inside it using `php artisan preset react` , it installed 15.4.2 version by default, and I want to update that to the latest react.js version to use new features like Suspense, how can I update the version?

Comment: If you could phrase this question as more of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be much easier to reproduce/test/answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use the command `php artisan preset react`, this creates a `package.json` in where are all your dependencies, you just modify the version of react and react-dom that you want to upgrade there and run `npm update`.

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
```